# Affects of Absolute Positioning on Voice Activation Software

Tags: css, css-position, accessibility, absolute, voice-recognition

Does using absolute positioning on a website negatively affect voice activation software?

**Context**:

I'm working for a company who have had their website's accessibility assessed. One of the comments was:

> The tick box shown here is not being picked up by Dragon.
>   This means that a voice activation user would need to use keyboard commands in order to tab onto them.
>
> Ensure that voice activation users are able to access the checkboxes by implementing the following in the CSS:
>
> ```css
> .checkbox__input {
>   /* position: absolute; */
>   cursor: pointer;
>   /* left: 0; */
>   /* top: 0; */
>   width: 38px;
>   height: 38px;
>   margin: 0;
>   opacity: 0;
> }
> ```

The commended-out properties are their suggestions on what we should remove from our CSS.

I am aware that using  `position: absolute` takes content out of the normal flow of the page. However, we are wrapping each checkbox in a container that is relatively positioned.

Their comment is suggesting to me that there is an issue around using voice commands on content that is absolutely positioned, but I can't seem to find anything online about if there actually are any issues.

For those curious, we do not want to implement their proposed changes because it changes our page design negatively.

Comment: How could we know? It seems insane one would let CSS affect content but their comment looks like a canned response and not one with thoughtful insight. Do they not have tech support or documentation at all?

Comment: @rob Sometimes CSS can affect accessibility negatively in terms of screen readers. Eg, when hiding content from the user one might accidentally hide it visually but not from a screen reader, as that requires a different/additional implementation. My question was meant to ask if there's some sort similar situation with CSS positioning more generally rather than exact implementation to Dragon. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP is asking about speech recognition, such as [Dragon](https://www.nuance.com/dragon.html), and not screen readers.

Positioning has nothing to do with speech recognition and the recommended CSS seems silly to me.  Two obvious things can affect speech recognition:

1. the role of the element
2. the displayed label of an element compared to the underlying accessible name

For the role, if you had a `<div>` that was styled to look like a checkbox, but the `<div>` did **not** have a `role="checkbox"`, then a speech recognition user would not be able to say "click checkbox".

For the label, if the visual label of the checkbox does not match the accessible name of the checkbox (which should be a rarity), then a speech recognition user might not be able to (directly) select the checkbox.  For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck">
<label for="mycheck">do you like dogs?</label>
```

A speech recognition user will be able to say "click dogs" or "click like" or "click *<any word that is part of the visible label*>".

However, if you had something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck" aria-label="are you a puppy lover?">do you like dogs?
```

then visually, both cases would look the same but the visible label, "do you like dogs?" does not match the accessible name, "are you a puppy lover?", and a speech recognition user would **not** be able to say "click dogs" or "click like" because neither of those words are in the accessible name.  They'd have to say "click puppy" or "click lover", which would not be obvious.

Now, regarding positioning, if you had an object that was "on top" of the checkbox and that object on top received click events, then *maybe* positioning might affect Dragon, but I'm not sure.  With a mouse user, if they try to click the checkbox but something (whether visually apparent or not) is on top, that top object will receive the event.  If the speech recognition user says "click *<checkbox name*>" and an object is on top of it, I don't know if the checkbox will receive the event.  It seems like the checkbox would get selected because you used the name of the checkbox and didn't rely on the DOM order for an object to receive the event.

Answer (score 2):

Screen readers typically follow the order of the HTML (including any HTML generated by scripts) when reading a document. When CSS is used to position content, the content that appears on the screen can appear be in a different order from what appears in the code.

From Penn State's Accessibility Office:

> The `position` attribute is used to change the visual position of an element regardless of where it is in the code. For example any item with `position:absolute` and position set to `top:0px` and `left:0px` will be displayed first visually, even if the div is the final text in the HTML code. Alternatively, an item may be listed first in the code, but actually be positioned to the bottom right side of the page visually.
>
> This can be a problem for screen reader accessibility because content can be read out of context and therefore be confusing.

http://accessibility.psu.edu/css/readorderhtml/#fxd

Relative positiong presents the same problem.

The only way to overcome this issue is to allow items to render on screen in the order that they appear in the HTML. This may mean making adjustments to your HTML code, scripts, templates, etc.

This doesn't mean that you can't use CSS to position and align things -- you certainly can. It just means that you shouldn't use CSS to re-arrange the order of things.